# How to extend a template in CrudGeneratorBundle skeleton views?

Tags: php, symfony

I have override my skeleton views of the generatorBundle like this post Can't override the standard skeleton views in Symfony2 GeneratorBundle but when i try to add a simple `{% extends "AcmeAdminBundle::layout.html.twig" %}` or a `{% extends "::layout.html.twig" %}` in skeleton/crud/views/index.html.twig , I have `"[Twig_error_loader] Unable to find template..."`

Answer (score 1):

We've extended the default bundle [here](https://github.com/newism/NSMGeneratorBundle) It might give you some tips.